# error in insatllation of hapi module of node

Tags: linux, node.js, installation, hapi.js

i want to install hapi module of node i am using the following command

```
npm install hapi
```

and i am getting the following error

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hapi

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: hapi
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-     client/request.js:136:18)

npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:209:10)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (http.js:1137:11)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/mohit/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "hapi"
npm ERR! cwd /home/mohit
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: hapi
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mohit/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

i am able to install other modules like request & express but getting error in installing hapi ,how to resolve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading node.js. You're using v0.6.x which is really old and uses an old version of npm. The current latest stable version of node (as of this writing) is v0.10.26 (which comes with npm 1.4.3).

EDIT: I can confirm that `npm install hapi` works with node v0.10.26.

Comment: can you tell how to install latest node version i am trying                   :    sudo apt-get install nodejs

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu you can use [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/) to get newer stable versions of node (for as far back as Ubuntu Lucid). If you're on Debian, you can get v0.10.26 from [wheezy-backports, jessie, or sid](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=nodejs&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: Solved ,i removed and installed the latest version of node and npm  and then tries installin hapi module and it workded thanks for your help